# Customise button in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qpushbutton

I need to create a toggle button in qt and it should look like the below image. It should show the ON image when  it is turned on and remain at this state until it is toggled again. It should show the OFF image in the off case. Please help me on this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can go with either custom Widget classes and draw those images in paint handler or you can go with easier route of using cascading style-sheets in QT, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use images as an icon (sadly, it won't scale with button by default), create a class which would paint those images in the handler for paint event, or you can use those images in *QSS stylesheet*. QSS is CSS 2.0 analog for Qt's GUI elements.

*Note that after using stylesheet all changes to visuals of said element should be done through changes to stylesheet as well.*

THose styles can be set through form editor by right-clicking a widget and choosing "Change stylesheet" or through code directly by calling `setStyleSheet`, depending which workflow you prefer.

```
button->setStyleSheet(
    "QPushButton {  border-image: url(:/Resources/chbUnchecked.png); }"
    "QPushButton::checked { border-image: url(:/Resources/chbChecked.png); }" );
```

`border-image` Scales image to border limits, replacing standard border.There is also a `background-image` which fills widget's surface with regular repeats.

To limit this change only for checkable buttons:

```
button->setStyleSheet(
    "QPushButton[checkable="true"] {    border-image: url(:/Resources/chbUnchecked.png); }"
    "QPushButton::checked[checkable="true"] {   border-image: url(:/Resources/chbChecked.png); }" );
```

`:/Resources/` is a path within app's resources.

QSS syntax: https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html

Note that QSS have selectors, so it's it have same "Cascading" ability as CSS. You can assign styles bulk based on hierarchical location on GUI, class-inheritances, class names, quasi-states and names.

If you set style above to a window, all instances of `QPushButton` within that window would have said style. If you define a new class for such Button, you can use its name instead of standard button class, although QSS for base class would apply to it.

Comment: Checked is a property of the QPushButton, so the selector should be `QPushButton:checked` instead of `QPushButton::checked`.

Comment: @felipegf both are correct, you can test that in Form Editor. Afaik, with small difference - `::` in this case permits applying other styles, If I remeber right (it was long ago I dabbled into that).

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to add the on-off images to your project as resources
then set the button as **checkable** and in its properties set the images to be rendered when is selected or not..(under **icon** -> **selected on** and **selected off**)

of course you have create images with a properly geometry... in the screenshot they look pretty small because I borrow them from your post..
:)

[image]

Comment: The  icon still leaves visible button border and text,  which requires some changes and stylesheeting to get rid of. Using border-image property is more preferable  based on what OP wrote